# How can I generate SQL code from GORM struct model?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm using goose to manage my database migrations but I need to write SQL sentences directly in the migrations file. There is a way to generate the SQL directly from the GORM model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately using the `gorm.Session{DryRun: true}` option doesn't make the migration SQL statement/s available to the caller as it does with normal queries.

The only way I can see right now would be to capture the SQL that is run by the migration when it's being logged by reimplementing the `gorm.io/gorm/logger.Interface` interface. Specifically, the `Trace` method.

```golang
type Interface interface {
    LogMode(LogLevel) Interface
    Info(context.Context, string, ...interface{})
    Warn(context.Context, string, ...interface{})
    Error(context.Context, string, ...interface{})
    Trace(ctx context.Context, begin time.Time, fc func() (string, int64), err error)
}
```

Inside `Trace` you can call that `fc` function argument to get the SQL and `RowsAffected`, which you can do whatever you want with.

For example:

```golang
import (
    "time"
    "context"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
)

type RecorderLogger struct {
    logger.Interface
    Statements []string
}

func (r *RecorderLogger) Trace(ctx context.Context, begin time.Time, fc func() (string, int64), err error) {
    sql, _ := fc()
    r.Statements = append(r.Statements, sql)
}
```

Now use it as:

```golang
recorder := RecorderLogger{logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info)}
session := db.Session(&gorm.Session{
    Logger: &recorder
})
session.AutoMigrate(&Model{}, ...)
// or 
session.Migrator().CreateTable(&Model{}, ...) // or any method therein
// now recorder.Statements contains the statements run during migration
```

This is very hacky, and you may run into problems because `AutoMigrate` modifies the current state of the database and migrates it up to what your model requires ([up to a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135691/automatically-delete-not-null-constraints-on-unused-columns-after-migration/66138024#66138024)) and for that to work your current database must reflect the current state of your production database (or whatever database your hope to migrate). So, you could build that tool that helps you get the migration script started if you're careful, but to properly gain the advantages of a migration system like `goose` you'll need to get your hands dirty with the SQL :)

Answer (score 2):

you can using this lib: https://github.com/sunary/sqlize

It's allowed you create sql from models, also support migration by differ between models and existing sql.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use the migration functionality that is available inside Gorm, but for your case we can do the following.

Firstly there is a feature in Gorm called Dry Run and you can use this to see the SQL statements that get executed when performing queries. Unfortunately I can't see that it is possible when using migrations. So what I suggest is to use `github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock`

I would usually use this for testing purposes, but you could use it temporarily to get the SQL needed for your separate migrations.

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "time"

    "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Model struct {
    ID          uint64 `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name        string `gorm:"index"`
    Description string
    CreatedAt   time.Time
    LastLogin   sql.NullTime
}

func main() {
    sqlDB, _, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    gormDB, err := gorm.Open(mysql.New(mysql.Config{
        Conn:                      sqlDB,
        SkipInitializeWithVersion: true,
    }), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer sqlDB.Close()

    gormDB.AutoMigrate(&Model{})
}
```

This will give you a result like this

```
all expectations were already fulfilled, call to ExecQuery 'CREATE TABLE `models` (`id` bigint unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,`name` varchar(191),`description` longtext,`created_at` datetime(3) NULL,`last_login` datetime(3) NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`),INDEX idx_models_name (`name`))' with args [] was not expected
[0.003ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE `models` (`id` bigint unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,`name` varchar(191),`description` longtext,`created_at` datetime(3) NULL,`last_login` datetime(3) NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`),INDEX idx_models_name (`name`))
```

which contains the SQL statement required. This feels incredibly hacky but will give you the result you need

Comment: Which is the available functionality inside GORM to perform migration? I want avoid the usage of `Automigrate`

Comment: Yeah `AutoMigrate` . The above should get you the sql that you need either way