# GORM: Getting the CREATE TABLE to migrate table manually

Tags: go, go-gorm

Isit possible to get the CREATE TABLE statement to manually create tables? Thinking perhaps its not a good practice to auto migrate on production? Eg. creating index on a large table may cause alot of performance issues?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate SQL code from GORM struct model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238657/how-can-i-generate-sql-code-from-gorm-struct-model)